# Data in the text view toggling while scrolling list view

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, toggle

I have a list view in which there are a text and a button in every row.When I click on the button the text in the text view changes.It is fine till now.But when I scroll the list view the text changes to its default text.Please help how can I show the changed text on button click in the list view when I scroll.

[image: img1]

I want like the above pic.But I am getting like the below pic when I am scrolling the list view

[image: img2]

Comment: post your adapter code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following steps:

1. You should use a array/ArrayList of your default texts like plus, plus... and then pass this array/ArrayList to your CustomListAdapter.
2. In you CustomListAdapter inside getView(): set the text on textview from the array/ArrayList.
3. On button click: You should update the string in your array/ArrayList, corresponding to clicked index and call notifyDataSetChanged().

Edited ans -

```
private void updateText(int position, String text) {
    arrayList.set(position, text);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call above method on both button clicks like

on minus button click- `updateText(position,"minus");`

on plus button click- `updateText(position,"plus");`

Comment: how can I update the arrayList corresponding to clicked index?Please help

Comment: By using inside your button click- arrayList.set(position,"minus");

Comment: Thank you.It's working.I want to ask one more thing.If there are two buttons side by side like one button named "plus" and another button named "minus".If I click on plus it will show "plus" and if I click on minus it will show "minus". How to achieve this?